# To get rid of spam/rude posts quickly, ask the users in the Charcoal HQ chat room

Tags: discussion

I recently discovered something, instead of flagging something as spam and then putting a link into the site chat, you can ask the users in the [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) room to report it.

On the two I have done so far, it has made the difference between spam being deleted in under 15 minutes instead of hours.

The Chat room is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), this should help it get deleted a lot faster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Charcoal member here. Some clarification:

- Manually reporting spam to us is awesome; obviously, cast a spam flag yourself as well to make it happen even quicker.
- Bear in mind that Charcoal focuses on spam - please don't report NAAs or close-worthy questions to us, there's nothing we can do about them.
- Spam flags from Charcoal mostly come from manually flagging the post. We do have an automatic flagging system that casts up to 4 (of the required 6) flags, but this will *only* trigger if the post hits our existing checks (i.e. not on manual reports).

A final note: reporting to Charcoal is useful in helping us maintain our checks and remove spam quickly, but don't let it become your primary method of spam removal - if Charcoal folds tomorrow, we don't want to leave y'all not knowing where the spam flag is!

Comment: That makes sense we have been flagging and then asking in our site chat but it’s way faster to ask on Charcoal

Comment: `maintain our checks and removing dogs quickly` - poor Undo. Always being taken out and not let back in.

Comment: While spam is the main focus, Charcoal also flags obvious rude/abusive posts.